# Can I make a jQuery UI Slider Respond to Click rather than Mousedown and Mouseup?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

As far as I've been able to work out, Jquery slider generates its slide event using mousedown and mouseup. However, I need it to respond to a **click** event by jumping to the clicked position, instead of mousedown/up combination.

Does anyone know if this is achievable?

(I know that physically clicking a mouse generates all three events, but this is for a "click"/activation event that is not triggered by a real mouse click)

Comment: I don't really understand what your looking for.  Can you clarify?  The "click"/activation event does not exist in the documentation.  You have "change", "create", "slide", "start", "stop"

Comment: @Trevor - my problem is that I need the slider to respond to the click event.

Comment: That seems to be the default behavior. look at https://jqueryui.com/slider/ if you click anywhere on the slider it responds accordingly.

Comment: @Trevor - yes, but I think that is because a mouse click also triggers a mousedown and mouseup event, which is recognised by the plugin. I would like the control to respond to the "click" event, as well as to mousedown/up.